# Recursive CTE - Employee with multiple Manager

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a table like follow

```
+-----------+------------+
| ManagerID | EmployeeID |
+-----------+------------+
| MAN001    | BOY001     |
| MAN001    | BOY002     |
| MAN001    | BOY003     |
| MAN001    | BOY004     |
| MAN001    | BOY005     |
| BOY005    | KID001     |
| BOY005    | KID002     |
| BOY005    | KID003     |
| BOY005    | KID004     |
| MAN002    | BOY005     |
| MAN002    | BOY004     |
| BOY004    | KID001     |
| BOY004    | KID002     |
| BOY004    | KID003     |
| BOY004    | KID004     |
| KID002    | SOM001     |
| KID002    | SOM002     |
| KID002    | SOM003     |
+-----------+------------+
```

The main point is that MAN001 does not exists in EmployeeID, meaning MAN001 is top level.
But BOY005 can work for MAN001 or MAN002 and more ...
The same with KID00X CAN work with Any manager MAN00X or BOY00X.

It is also possible that 
KID001 KID002 KID003 KID004   may have an employee, eg KID002 has three Employee SOM001 SOM002 and SOM003
BUT BOY005 will never be an employee of KID because we know that BOY005 is the manager for KID.

The output that I would like to get is as follow, where the column E can grow as much as the data has.

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
|   M1   |   E1   |   E2   |   E3   |  ...  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| MAN001 | BOY001 |        |        |       |
| MAN001 | BOY002 |        |        |       |
| MAN001 | BOY003 |        |        |       |
| MAN001 | BOY004 |        |        |       |
| MAN001 | BOY005 | KID001 |        |       |
| MAN001 | BOY005 | KID002 |        |       |
| MAN001 | BOY005 | KID003 |        |       |
| MAN001 | BOY005 | KID004 |        |       |
| MAN001 | BOY005 | KID002 | SOM001 |       |
| MAN001 | BOY005 | KID002 | SOM002 |       |
| MAN001 | BOY005 | KID002 | SOM003 |       |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
```

I tried to follow this basic simple recursive cte. But the example does not consider if an employee exists in multiple manager.
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/28/sql-server-simple-example-of-recursive-cte/

Also another different case with the blog post above is in my case Top level ManagerID simply don't exists in EmployeeID

```
WITH Emp_CTE AS (
SELECT EmployeeID, ManagerID
FROM Employee
WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT e.EmployeeID, , e.ManagerID
FROM HumanResources.Employee e
INNER JOIN Emp_CTE ecte ON ecte.EmployeeID = e.ManagerID
)
SELECT *
FROM Emp_CTE
```

Thank you

EDIT1:

This is pretty close to what I am looking for. 
I Also think KID00X cannot be directly Under MAN001.
Is there a more efficient automated way?

```
select PC.ManagerID,PC.EmployeeID,PC2.EmployeeID,PC3.EmployeeID
, PC4.EmployeeID, PC5.EmployeeID
from Employee PC
LEFT JOIN (select ManagerID,EmployeeID from Employee
where ManagerID in (select EmployeeID from Employee))PC2 ON PC2.ManagerID=PC.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN (select ManagerID,EmployeeID from Employee
where ManagerID in (select EmployeeID from Employee
where ManagerID in (select EmployeeID from Employee)))PC3 ON PC3.ManagerID=PC2.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN (select ManagerID,EmployeeID from Employee
where ManagerID in (select EmployeeID from Employee
where ManagerID in (select EmployeeID from Employee
where ManagerID in (select EmployeeID from Employee))))PC4 ON PC4.ManagerID = PC3.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN (select ManagerID,EmployeeID from Employee
where ManagerID in (select EmployeeID from Employee
where ManagerID in (select EmployeeID from Employee
where ManagerID in (select EmployeeID from Employee
where ManagerID in (select EmployeeID from Employee)))))PC5 ON PC5.ManagerID = PC4.EmployeeID
Order by PC.ManagerID,PC.EmployeeID,PC2.EmployeeID,PC3.EmployeeID 
, PC4.EmployeeID, PC5.EmployeeID
```

Comment: The biggest challenge you are going to have here is the dynamic number of columns. The recursive cte isn't really a big deal but needing the traverse back up the tree is going to be very challenging and also very likely a huge performance issue. You might take a look at this article for a slightly different approach to the problem. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Hierarchy/94040/

Comment: thanks. I write the recursive query the manual way in the original post. is it possible to optimize that or even to some how automate the recursive? Thanks again I'll look into your link

Comment: Your edit may or may not work. With that formatting it is just a wall of text that is illegible. The problem with it from looking though is that is limited to 5 levels. What happens when you get one more level? This is why you will have to use dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @select NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @from VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @cnt INT
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @countsql NVARCHAR(max)

SET @i = 1
SET @select = 'SELECT emp1.managerid as m1, emp1.employeeid as e1';
SET @from = ' FROM employee emp1 LEFT JOIN employee emp0 ON emp1.managerid=emp0.employeeid ';

SET @countsql = 'SELECT @cnt = COUNT(emp1.managerid) '
                + @from + 'WHERE emp0.employeeid IS NULL AND emp' + cast(@i as varchar(10))
                + '.employeeid IS NOT NULL' 

EXEC sp_executesql @countsql, N'@cnt int out', @cnt OUT

WHILE @cnt > 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @select + @from + ' WHERE emp0.employeeid IS NULL'
    SET @i = @i + 1

    SET @select = @select + ', emp' + cast(@i as varchar(10)) + '.employeeid as e'
                  + cast(@i as varchar(10))
    SET @from = @from + 'LEFT JOIN employee emp' + cast(@i as varchar(10)) + ' ON emp'
                  + cast(@i as varchar(10)) + '.managerid=emp'
                  + cast(@i - 1 as varchar(10)) + '.employeeid '

    SET @countsql = 'SELECT @cnt = COUNT(emp1.managerid) ' + @from
                    + 'WHERE emp0.employeeid IS NULL AND emp' + cast(@i as varchar(10))
                    + '.employeeid IS NOT NULL'
    EXEC sp_executesql @countsql, N'@cnt int out', @cnt OUT
END

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```